# Importing Eclipse Library Project into AndroidStudio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, library-project

I have an Eclipse Project that I like to migrate to AndroidStudio, with the following Structure/Content

- 1 LibraryProject with most of classes for all my Apps. This Library has 1 Activity ("SharedStarterActivity"), which will be started from all my 3 Apps.
- 3 Apps using the mentioned LibraryProject. These Apps referencing an Activity of my ProjectLibrary App as the Start Activity in the Apps AndroidManifest.xml.

  ```
  <activity android:name=".SharedStarterActivity"
            android:label="@string/IndividualAppName">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  ```

In a first look, it does not make sense, but each app has its individual AppProp.class, which is used by the SharedStarterActivity.class and makes each app individual.

Now my question:
How can I migrate this Projects to AndroidStudio ?

I have read [the migration guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html) "from Eclipse to AndroidStudio", but I am stuck now at

> "Import Eclipse Projects to Android Studio" -> You should decide how
>   you will import your existing Eclipse ADT projects depending on their
>   structure:

Before Trial and Erroring, I wanted to ask you experts, how you would import the projects and will the mechanic still work with referencing an Activity from LibraryProject
in my Android Project (one of the 3 Apps) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see there is more types available in Google to migrate eclips to studio but which method I use please follow the step.

1) Open existing project in eclipse remove the library from setting and close eclipse

2) Open AS(Android Studio) import from eclipse option available there, choose the option and open your project in AS.

3) Some Library are already avail in AS. Click on your Main module (Main) press F4 open setting and check your lib available in listing or not.

4) if Avail then add from there else find the latest version of same library and add as module to your Main project.

5) please properly configure your Gradle ( Main Gradle and app Gradle file)

you may also refer below link to migrate in details

https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html

or

http://www.developer.com/ws/android/migrating-from-eclipse-to-android-studio.html